# How to catch an incoming text message

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to be able to control incoming text messages.  My application is still on a "proof of concept" version and I'm trying to learn Android programming as I go.

First my application need to catch incoming text messages.  And if the message is from a known number then deal with it.  If not, then send the message as nothing has happened to the default text message application.

I have no doubt it can be done, but I still have some concern and I see some pitfalls at how things are done on Android.

So getting the incomming text message could be fairly easy - except when there are other messaging applications installed and maybe the user wants to have normal text messages to pop up on one of them - and it will, after my application has had a look at it first.

How to be sure my application get first pick of incoming text messages?

And after that I need to send most text messages through to any other text message application the user has chosen so the user can actually read the message my application didn't need.

Since Android uses intents that are relative at best, I don't see how I can enforce my application to get a peek at all incoming text messages, and then stop it or send it through to the default text messaging application.

Answer (score 2):

Espen,

The answer to this is multi-part. Understand first that our company has resolved this problem, but the solution is temporarily proprietary, so I will answer what I can without causing conflict either here or for my company.

1) You can never insure that your App ever gets first pick. What you can do is make your processing "fast enough" that is does not matter.

2) Intents ARE an absolute if you force the issue. Our company uses a concept called intent routing. This insures that the data is sent to the appropriate app. The most basic idea is that when you receive the SMS, you create a New Intent (not the same one) and send it to the class directly. This has some special considerations, but should give you some direction.

Unfortunately, without violating my company's confidence or stackoverflow's policies, I cannot say anymore publicly until the solution is made public (within the next month).

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Hi FuzzialLogic, please gimme this code-sample when its published, it sound really interessting..! And it could be a good advance to my app!

Comment: Safari, it is actually an api solution now. We converted over to API/App in order to do a bunch of neat things. If you are interested in what we are doing, you may like us on Facebook or follow us on LinkedIn. The company is nTouch Software (on Facebook it has to have a capital N). That's about all I can say without turning this into an advert which neither I nor StackOverflow wants.

Comment: (I only put the above comment, because I found no way to send a direct message without the user's email published.) :( Feel free to delete the comment, as I'm sure it deserves to be :)

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic I couldn't find u on Facebook, there is aplenty pages with the same name (NTouch)

Comment: nTouch Software is my company. The truth is that I've been rather lax with the company's facebook page since I've been working with Extended Dialog. If you need to contact me or my company, you may send an email to the gmail account of ntouchsoftware.

Answer (score 0):

Retriving all incoming messages is just setting up listener, you can do it easily [see here](http://tinyurl.com/38bsbfk)

and after that, its fine if you are at do nothing phase, but in case you want to prevent sms to go into the native messaging app it is not advisable to prevent user.

better you wait for some time and then delete the same from SMS database.

Comment: Thanx.  But what I'm trying to do is from my application to send a text message to a service - let's say a bank service.  And to intercept any messages comming from the same number.

So when the user clicks a button in my application to get the balance, it sends a message to a number and my application intercepts the return message.

So it is very important that my application get first pick of the incomming messages and that it can pass through any messages that doesn't come from a known number.

My concern here is that intents are not an absolute and so can make this impossible.